# NodeJS '/' home route is working but the remaining routes are not working (CPanel Shared Hosting)

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I have a problem when I deploy my NodeJS API on CPANEL shared hosting.
My application is working very well on localhost but when I deploy it, the home route is the only one working, all remaining routes are not working (500 Internal error). I use Express.

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

// Import Routes
const productsRoute = require('./routes/products');

// Middleware
const corsOpts = {
  origin: '*',

  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],

  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
};

app.use(cors(corsOpts));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());


app.use('/products', productsRoute);
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World !'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("OK");
});

app.listen();
```

[Cpanel configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrha7.jpg)

Can somebody Help me please ?

Thank you !

Comment: The problem is likely not your Node application but the Apache configuration pointing back at your application.

Comment: @selfagency Yes that's what I think. But I don't know how to figure it out

Comment: Did you follow [this guide](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/)?

Comment: No I use the NodeJS Setup rather than Application Manager. You can see the configuration in the topic. @selfagency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the case after testing many methods. It was a passenger configuration problem
In my generated .htaccess file, I add the following lines on the top

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^server/(.*)?$ https://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

And in my nodeJS app I listen on port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Application Manager installed in your cPanel, otherwise contact with your Hosting provider to install Application Manger in the WHM.

1. You can run from the terminal by adding
   export PATH=/opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs16/bin/:$PATH
   at your .bashrc file

OR

2. You can setup/register your node application from the Application Manager at your cPanel